# SSL, Express, Nodejs: Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

Tags: node.js, express, ssl

i tried to add certificates to my nodeJs, Express server like this:

```
cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/private.key'),
key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/your_domain_name.crt'),
ca: [
    fs.readFileSync('path/to/CA_root.crt'),
    fs.readFileSync('path/to/ca_bundle_certificate.crt')
]
```

and i got this error

```
      c.context.setKey(key, passphrase);
                ^

Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:151:17)
    at Server.setSecureContext (_tls_wrap.js:1155:27)
    at Server (_tls_wrap.js:1033:8)
    at new Server (https.js:65:14)
    at Object.createServer (https.js:89:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (********)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  library: 'PEM routines',
  function: 'get_name',
  reason: 'no start line',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE'
}
```

does anyone faced this problem please?

Thanks by advance

Comment: I am also facing this issue as well.

Comment: How are you generating your Key?

Answer (score 0):

Your may write wrong file name in cert and key section.
key: section need private key filename and cert: section need certification filename.
I switched your filename in cert and key section.

```
cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/your_domain_name.crt'),
key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/private.key'),
ca: [
    fs.readFileSync('path/to/CA_root.crt'),
    fs.readFileSync('path/to/ca_bundle_certificate.crt')
]
```